# How to transfer Ether from a smart contract to an account?

Tags: solidity, transactions, balances, payable, transfer

I wrote a very simple smart contract. The goal is to:

1. transfer some Ether from an **account A** to the smart-contract
2. and then from the smart-contract to another **account B**.

Here is the contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract {

    function fundContract() external payable {

    }

    function getBalance() public view returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function transferAmount(address payable _recipient) external payable {
        _recipient.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    function callAmount(address payable _recipient) external payable {
        (bool success,  bytes memory data) = _recipient.call{value:msg.value}("");
        require(success, "Transaction Failed!");

    }

}
```

I was able to achieve to transfer 5 ETH from an **account A** to the smart contract by using the following commands on the `truffle console`:

```
MyContract.deployed().then(function(i) { contract=i;})
contract.fundContract({value: 500000000000000000})
contract.getBalance().then(function(r){result=r;})
parseFloat(result)
```

However when I try to send 1 ETH from the smart contract to another **account B** using these line of code:

```
contract.transferAmount('0x60407B3b7a3acd2dAE922610129433B915A3C238', {value:100000000000000000})
```

or

```
contract.callAmount('0x60407B3b7a3acd2dAE922610129433B915A3C238', {value:100000000000000000})
```

the amount is subtracted from the user's balance (**account A**) rather than the smart-contract, which appears to have 5 ETH instead of 4 ETH (since I am trying to transfer 1 ETH). What am I doing wrong? Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant way to achieve this goal (send 1 ETH from the smart-contract balance to **account B**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `transferAmount`, you're supplying `value`, meaning you're sending additional ETH to the contract - which you don't want. `transferAmount` then continues to send this value to the recipient (using `msg.value`).

Instead of having `transferAmount` payable and sending ETH to it, add another parameter to `transferAmount`: `uint _amount`. Then this is the amount you should transfer to the recipient.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!!